# Sincronizar datos insertados en tabla del modelo mysql con workbrench

Tags: mysql-workbench

¡Buenos días! Estoy intentando crear la base de datos desde el DER con Myql Workbrench 8.0
En el DER tengo la posibilidad de insertar valores en las tablas
[image: DER]

Mi duda es: Se pueden sincronizar estos valores con la base de datos?
Hasta ahora solo pude sincronizar tablas vacías.
¡Gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de la pestaña en la que te encuentras y una vez insertados los datos y presionando el boton 'Apply changes to data':

1 -> click derecho en file > export > Forward Engineer SQL create script

2 -> elige el directorio donde guardaras el script para tu tabla, asegúrate de que la opcion 'generate INSERT statements for tables' este activada, click en next.

3 -> en la seccion 'export MySQL table object' y asegurandote con el checkbox de que esta activada, presiona el boton 'show filter' y se mostraran todas las tablas de tu modelo, las tablas de tu interes deben quedar del lado izquierdo y las que quieres excluir en el derecho, click en next.

4 -> te mostrara una pantalla con el script que se creó en el directorio seleccionado en el paso 2, tienes la opción de pegarlo en el portapapeles.

Y listo, ya puedes usar el script para crear la tabla en tu base de datos ya que contiene los inserts necesarios para hacerlo, igual te dejo un pequeño .gif

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(perdón por la calidad)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!! Acabo de probarlo me funcionó.
Entendí todo a la perfección.